# How to create items list every time when combobox open?

Tags: c++, qt, qcombobox

I want to check the state of some list in my program every time when a user opens Combobox and if the list was changed change the string list in Combobox. I find that I can reimplement `showPopup` but I can't think of a way to do it with this function.

**How I should do this?**

Comment: Combobox accept a model, so if you don't want to attach signal everytime your data are changed just provide a proper list model and it will update automatically

Comment: @Moia is right. You shouldn't be manually telling your Combobox to check if the data has changed. The data should be sending a signal whenever it has changed, and the Combobox should update automatically. There's tons of examples of this online.